# how to make magento store 'to search' any word in e-shop, not only products

Tags: magento, search

I have installed great extension - "News Extension 2.2"

And then any news are added, I can't to search it.

I try to use: 
"Free Text Search" extension, it search CMS pages, but didn't reach news. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Magento won't do this natively. Like you said, you need to use an extension. I've never used "Free Text Search" so I'm not sure how (or if) it works, I would recommend swyftype - https://swiftype.com/

Its not a magento extension out of the box, but can be easily integrated if you know a little bit about how magento works.